# AngularJS Factories - Access private variables from methods

Tags: angularjs, factory

I wrote the following factory :

```
.factory('UserFact', function() {
  var user = [];
  return {
  'setUser': function(user) {
    this.user = user;
      console.log('(1) User set: ' + this.user);
      console.log('(2) User id is now: ' + this.user.uid);
  },
  'updateSport': function(sportid) {
    console.log('(3)Update sport ' + sportid + 'for user id ' + this.user.uid);
  }
}
```

Use it the following way in my controller :

```
function ($scope, $stateParams, DatabaseFact, UserFact) {

  // variables
  $scope.sports = [];
  $scope.sports = DatabaseFact.getSports();

  // functions
  $scope.updateSport = UserFact.updateSport;

  // execution
  UserFact.setUser({uid: '123456', name: 'forrest'});
}
```

And trigger it from my view through a list of trigger button :

```
updateSport(sport.id)
```

My problem is that console logs print the following :

```
(1) User set: [Object] Object
(2) User id is now: 123456
(3) Update sport 1 for user id undefined
```

Do you know why my user id is undefined in log 3?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how familiar you are with JavaScript, but I suspect you're being caught out by the `this` reference being different in your two function calls.

To debug this try logging `this` to the console in both functions. You should observe that they differ, which explains the cause of your problem.

The fix could be to not use the `this` keyword, e.g. function `setUser` would become:

```
'setUser': function(_user) {
    user = _user;
}
```

You can find more information on JS `this` on Google, try https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this for a start.

Comment: I come from C++ and Java. I am having really hard time with scopes in Javascript which looks much harder to understand in JS...

Answer (score 1):

That makes sense to me, due to the reason of its implementation. In your controller, you are actually copying the method reference to $scope.updateSport. So whenever the method gets executed, it executes in the context of the controller and this -> $scope instance but not one the service instance.

As your controller doenst have uid, it just returns undefined.

To fix this you need to have a method body for updateSort and call UserFact.updateSport

```
$scope.updateSport = function(){
    UserFact.updateSport();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's undefined because your function uses `this`, but is copied from its original object (the user service) to the scope.

You can either stop to use `this`, and instead use the `user` variable that you declared and initialized to an empty array (why, BTW?), but never used anywhere else, or do

```
$scope.updateSport = function() {
    UserFact.updateSport;
}
```

Note that you named your service "UserFact", but it's not a factry. It doesn't create anything. It only allows setting a user and updating its sport. That is not a factory. A factory is an object used to create things. The factory, here, is the function passed to module.factory(), and which is used to create and return the service instance, which should better be called `UserService`.

Comment: I come from C++ and I am used to initialize variables of type they are about to become ; here user is an array. You recommend anything else? Also, I couldn't find any understandable explanation on true difference between Factory vs. Service? Any suggestion?

Comment: A service is what controllers, and other services use. Services are what is injected by angular in other services, controllers, directives, etc. The object, with its two methods setUser() and updateSport(), is the service. The function you pass to the factory() function is the factory: it creates and returns the service. And given that you're calling `UserFact.setUser({uid: '123456', name: 'forrest'});`, the user is not an array. It's an object.